# What is the correct Git p4 workflow?

Tags: git, merge, perforce, git-rebase

I set up a git repository using the instructions here: https://git.help.collab.net/entries/22564277-Migration-from-Perforce-to-GIT

I have a master branch where I get the latest from perforce and where I submit my changes to perforce. I also have a development branch where I do my work, sometimes I will have a feature branch (branched from development).

I've been trying to figure out the correct workflow, here is where I'm at now - please correct me if there a better way.

1) git checkout master

2) git p4 rebase (get the latest from perforce, should I use "git p4 sync" instead?)

3) git checkout development

3) git merge master (update the development to the latest)

4) git commit.. (do all my work and commits)

5) git checkout master (get ready to merge development to branch

6) git p4 sync (pull the latest from perforce)

7) git merge development

8) resolve any conflicts

9) git p4 rebase (pull the latest from perforce then rebase my committed changes on top of it)

10) git p4 submit

Should "git p4 rebase" only be used at right before a "git p4 commit"?
Also for my model/workflow is merging better than rebasing?

Comment: I think #9 should go after #6 then merge dev resolve and submit.

Answer (score 2):

From  [http://owenou.com/2011/03/23/git-up-perforce-with-git-p4.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20141002180757/https://owenou.com/2011/03/23/git-up-perforce-with-git-p4.html):

Commands

Four things to remember when using git-p4:

```
Instead of using “git push” to push local commits to remote repository, use “git-p4 submit”
Instead of using “git fetch” to fetch changes from remote repository to local, use “git-p4 sync”
Instead of using “git pull” to fetch and merge changes from remote repository to local, use “git-p4 rebase”
Instead of using “git merge” to merge local branches, use “git rebase”
```

For the last one, the reason is that when you run “git merge”, Git creates an extra commit on top of the stack for the merging. This is not something we wanna show in the remote non-git repository. So we merge code with “git rebase”.

Comment: As for the last point, I'm not into p4, but my experience talking with other non-git VCSes is that they just can't represent the kind of tangled history git manages effortlessly, so you have to feed them a linear sequence. Or at least merges have to be done on the central repository using special tools/commands.